# Deno Lint - Disable / add rules to linter

Tags: visual-studio-code, deno, deno-lint

currently I'm developing the backend of my website with Deno in Typescript and I am using their linter `Deno lint`. 
But since the beginning of my new project, I can't find out how to modify the linter properly.

[Deno lint doc](https://deno.land/manual/tools/linter) says that its supporting most eslint rules and my goal would be to add some rules like `eol-last` or `eslint semi`.

Does anybody has some experince with deno and it's linter and wants to share it?

Comment: configuration and plugin-support are in the pipeline, see [roadmap](https://github.com/denoland/deno_lint/issues/176)

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use `// deno-lint-ignore-file` or `// deno-lint-ignore <codes...>`.